# How to open a page in a new window or tab from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a webapplication where I select a value from a dropdownlist. When this value is selected, I want to load another page in a new window.

I tried this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('Default.aspx', '_blank');", true);
```

It does open the page, but not in a new window/tab. It opens it in the current opened page.

Alternatively I tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openDashboardPage()</script>");
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.open('Default.aspx', '_new');</SCRIPT>");
```

They all behave in the same fashion. I just loads the page in the existing window. I tried it in both Firefox and Chrome, thinking it might be a browser thing, but they both behaved the same.

How do I open a new window?

Comment: set target="_blank" I guess..that can help you

Comment: Sometimes you also need to wrap call into jquery function like that: $(openDashboardPage)

Comment: I am not entirely sure where I would have to add the target="_blank" part, since that would be HTML. But I'll look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one

```
string redirect = "<script>window.open('http://www.google.com');</script>"; 
Response.Write(redirect);
```

Comment: Did you try this method. i have tested it and working in all major browsers

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me:

```
Dim script As String = "<script type=""text/javascript"">window.open('" & URL.ToString & "');</script>"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "openWindow", script)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

Target= "_blank" property of anchor tag

Comment: this worked for me (opened in new tab).  My situation was I had a hyperlink control (HyperlinkSharepoint) so I added HyperlinkSharepoint.Target = "_blank"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Target= "_blank"
```

This does it in html, give it a try in C#

Answer (score -1):

You can use `scriptmanager.registerstartupscript` to call a `JavaScript function`.

Inside that function, you can open a new window.