# open asp.net page in new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile-safari

I'm trying to open asp.net page in new window while loading itself. I tried with the following code. But it is opening in the same window not in the new window.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent != null)
        {
            var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();

            if (userAgent.Contains("iphone;"))
            {
                // iPhone
                Form.Target = "_blank";

            }


        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145187/how-to-open-a-page-in-a-new-window-or-tab-from-code-behind

Answer (score 13):

Use a Javascript in code behind to redirect :

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('http://www.google.com.hk/','_blank');</script>");
```

Or use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) and you can pass parameters too:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('YourPage.aspx?Param=" + ParamX.ToString() + "');",true);
```

Or if you have a button you can use it as below:

```
Button1.OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('YourPage.aspx?Param=" + ParamX.ToString() + "');";
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what i done, just try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('ViewDetails.aspx','mywindow','menubar=1,resizable=1,width=900,height=600');", true);
```